# How to update image title and alt tags

Tags: media, feeds, importing-exporting, views

I am using Drupal Commerce.
Images are in product entities.
I have imported my products and nodes with feeds, but now I am working on SEO of my website, I have realised that my 'title' and 'alt' tags are empty.
I am looking for a process to update these tags with the image title :

- With Feeds I haven't found the way to update these tags ?
- I tried ([How to bulk update image alt and title?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/58137/how-to-bulk-update-image-alt-and-title)) with VBO but it doesn't work.

This issue sounds common and trivial but I can't find a solution. Am I missing something ? Is there an other way to automatically replace title and alt image tags with image field title ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

The way I deal with this issue is to use the [ImageField Tokens](https://drupal.org/project/imagefield_tokens) module:

> The ImageField Tokens module extends the default functionality of
>   Image fields adding the ability to specify default values and use node
>   tokens in the Alt and Title text.

The module [Token](https://drupal.org/project/token) is required. After you install and enable the modules, you configure its settings in the field properties for each individual content type.