# How do I bulk update the alt and title tags of images

Tags: 8, media

Is there a way to bulk update image title and alt tags? Where do alt and title tags are saved in the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewriting the D7 code of [How to bulk update image alt and title?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/58137/how-to-bulk-update-image-alt-and-title/58139#58139)

```
$nodes = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('node')
  ->loadByProperties(['type' => 'article']);

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
  $node->field_image->alt = $alt;
  $node->field_image->title = $title;

  $node->save();
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to uniquely identify the image of a node? Because I need to import those from a csv file.

Comment: Sure, if for example the filenames match you can check `$node->field_image->entity->filename->value`

Comment: `$node->field_image->alt = $alt;` doesn't change the value.

Comment: This example is for the core content type `article`. Debug `$node->toArray()`, here you'll should find the properties alt and title of an image field in your content type.